# Collapse duplicated rows simultaneously on several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

R beginner here. I currently have a database with over 33 variables for over 10000 species of animals and have just got myself into a bit of a trouble.

Summing up, my data looks something like this:

```
species1     species2    info1    info2
Parrot       Parrot      3        NA 
NA           Parrot      NA       7
Osprey       NA          NA       89
Sparrow      Sparrow     NA       19
Sparrow      NA          27       NA
NA           Duck        69       16
```

What i'm trying to do here is to collapse or merge together rows that have duplicates on species columns, while keeping those rows that have NA. Something like this:

```
species1     species2    info1    info2
Parrot       Parrot      3        7
Osprey       NA          NA       89
Sparrow      Sparrow     27       19
NA           Duck        69       16
```

I have tried with `group_by`, but apart from the fact that it only groups by one variable, im not sure it is the correct way. I have 5 other species rows that may also have duplicates on them, should i just use this for each one?

```
data %>% 
  group_by(species1) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(max))
```

Sorry if this is too obvious, im just a novice!
Tank you!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could `coalesce` the 'species1', 'species2' columns to a single column, do a grouping on the `coalesce`d column before doing the `summarise` and remove it with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(species = coalesce(species1, species2)) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1]))%>% 
   select(-species)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  species1 species2 info1 info2
  <chr>    <chr>    <int> <int>
1 <NA>     Duck        69    16
2 Osprey   <NA>        NA    89
3 Parrot   Parrot       3     7
4 Sparrow  Sparrow     27    19
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(species1 = c("Parrot", NA, "Osprey", "Sparrow", 
"Sparrow", NA), species2 = c("Parrot", "Parrot", NA, "Sparrow", 
NA, "Duck"), info1 = c(3L, NA, NA, NA, 27L, 69L), info2 = c(NA, 
7L, 89L, 19L, NA, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I still have a question: what if one of the species columns had values with a different name? (lets say like a synonym, Duck1 for example) The the coalesce grouping would not be effective, right? What could i do in that case?

Comment: @Prego `coalesce` works in a way that if the corresponding row is NA for the first argument, it replaces with the non-NA from second argument.  If there are digits at the end, we could remove those with `group_by(species = stringr::str_remove(coalesce(species1, species2), "\\d+$"))`

Comment: Okay, and what if the species synonym was completely different? Like Mallard and Duck, and i wanted it to keep both in their own species column and same row

Comment: @Prego that would be a separate question because it involves using different functions.  Can you post as a new question.  thanks

Comment: @Prego  By loooking at the post.  I think you may need a key/value pair dataset or list because this is very specific and there is no pattern to match those